# EarthEngine - Layer error: Image.parseExpression: Expression parse error

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, parse

I am trying to create a layer using conditional statement in Google Earth Engine. I have created a stack of two layers as follows:

```js
var NDVI_2000_2001_2002 = NDVI_2001_2000.addBands(NDVI_2002_2000);
```

Now, I want to create a layer with three classes, where common pixels having values greater than 0.2 in both the layers (NDVI_2001_2000 and NDVI_2002_2000) will be assigned a new value 3; values less than -0.2  a new value of 1 and everything else will be assigned a value of 2. I am using the conditional statement as follows:

```js
var Change_2000_2001 = NDVI_2000_2001_2002.expression(
    "(b('NDVI_2001_2000', 'NDVI_2002_2000')) > 0.2 ? 3" +
      ": (b('NDVI_2001_2000', 'NDVI_2002_2000')) > -0.2) ? 2" +
        ": 1"
    );
```

I am getting the following error:

> Layer 2: Layer error: Image.parseExpression: Expression parse error at
> character 97: '(b('NDVI_2001_2000', 'NDVI_2002_2000')) > 0.2 ? 3:
> (b('NDVI_2001_2000', 'NDVI_2002_2000')) > -0.2) ? 2: 1'
> ^.

I have not been able to identify where exactly the correction needs to be done.

Comment: Please include a full (but minimal) runnable example that demonstrates the error, so that others can reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have too many parenthesis in your expression.  The one after "-0.2" is mismatched.

But the operation you're doing is being applied to each layer independently, so a) you're getting 2 output layers and b) if you're hoping for a 3 when both layers are > 0.2, you're going to need to do some boolean comparisons.  Something like:

```
"(b(0) > 0.2 && b(1)) > 0.2 ? 3 : (b(0) > -0.2 && b(1) > -0.2) ? 2 : 1"
```